# How to get input field above keyboard as android/ios in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

I am trying to get user input as like in android or iOS. i.e whenever i enter value to any input fields the user input should be shown above the keyboard region.

[image]

Any suggestion would be more helpful.

Comment: Add  padding to fields on keyboard open.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this

Comment: @noor please do have a look on this https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7149 i solved it by listening event and used some css.